# reference error prop not defined, body parser not working, node, express, nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer, body-parser

I have a form that I want to send data to an email subscriber via `STMP` using `nodemailer` in `express`. I am not permitted to use a database, and I am getting an error with the `body-parser middleware`.

Errors I got from the client: `Request failed with status code 404`,`ERR_BAD_REQUEST`.

Errors I got from server: `ReferenceError: firstnameprop is not defined` when attempting to start server `

The only time I can send the test email I wrote in `nodemailer` is when the server restarts. My goal is to send the data from the form only when the request is sent, not by restarting the server.

In the past using a database, controllers, and routes I was successful in integrating client and server side to communicate. Without a database, I am not able to declare the prop.

My question is what is wrong with the `body-parser`? (yes it is installed) How else can I troubleshoot? Am I missing anything?

---

UPDATE: I added headers to `Axios req`, and updated `server.js

2ND UPDATE: got the client to work, I changed `app.get` to `app.post`, server still returning undefined

---

[image: package.json]

[image: server error]

index.js

const express = require("express");

// app

```
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

// morgan
app.use(morgan("tiny"));

app.use(jsonParser); // use it globally
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cors());

// server routee
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello world" });
});

// send route route
app.post("/send-email", jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  const { firstnameprop } = req.body;
  console.log("response", res);
}); 

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.office365.com",
  port: 465,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: "...",
    pass: "...",
  },
});

let mailOptions = {
  from: "someemail.com",
  to: "someemail.com",
  subject: "Sending Email using Node.js",
  text: `Name: ${firstnameprop}`,

  //ERROR IS BELOW, PROP IS NOT DELARED, HOW CAN I FIX THIS?
  html: `<html><body><h1>Hello ${firstnameprop} !</h1><p>This is a test from development server from website.com/</p></body></html>`,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
    }
  });

  app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Server started on port 5000");
  });
```

HireingForm.js

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Card, Col, Form, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
//some more imports

const HiringForm = () => {
const matchSm = useMediaQuery("(max-width: 728px)");
const refForm = useRef();

// props
const [firstnameprop, setFirstNameProp] = useState("");

const sendEmailHandler = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log("submitted list", firstnameprop);

 axios
    .post(
      "http:.localhost:5000/send-email", 
       { firstnameprop },
        {
          headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};


   {/* NOTE, THE FORM WORKS, I CONSOLED THE PROP AND WAS SUCCESSFUL WITH THE LOG */}
   return (
   <>
     <Form
       ref={refForm}
       onSubmit={sendEmailHandler}
       className={hiring}
       autoComplete="on"
      >
       <FirstName
       firstnameprop={firstnameprop}
       setFirstNameProp={setFirstNameProp}
       />
       {!checked ? <SubmitButton /> : <SubmitButtonDisabled />}
     </Form>
    </>
  
  export default HiringForm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer:

The problem was in both the client where I had `/send-email endpoint`, and I changed it to `http://localhost5000/send-email`
I also added a header"

```
 axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:5000/send-email",
        { firstnameprop },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Solution for the server, after researching and [finding this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870325/nodemon-server-with-axios-unable-to-send): I implemented the code and made some additional changes, I will paste it below:

As you see I changed the `app.post` to a `try and catch` including some `plain HTML`, and `smtpTransport.sendMail function` Notice the `smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport function` was OUTISDE the `try catch function`. I passed the `firstnameprop` with `req.body.firstnameprop` and `not const {firstnameprop} = req.body` I found not using a `HTML` template in this case was best.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");

// morgan
app.use(morgan("tiny"));
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
let smtpTransport = require("nodemailer-smtp-transport");

app.use(jsonParser); // use it globally
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // to support URL-encoded bodies
app.use(cors());

//server route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello world" });
});

//CHANGES START HERE --------------------------------------
app.post("/send-email", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    const mailOptions = {
      from: "…",
      to: "…",
      subject: "Sending Email Test",
      html: `
      <p>You have a new contact request.</p>
      <h3>Contact Details</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Name: ${req.body.firstnameprop}</li>
      </ul>
      `,
    };

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
          success: false,
          message: "Something went wrong. Try again later",
        });
      } else {
        res.send({
          success: true,
          message: "Thanks for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly",
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({
      success: false,
      message: "Something went wrong. Try again later",
    });
  }
});

smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
  smtpTransport({
    host: "...",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "...",
      pass: "...",
    },
  })
);

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 5000");
});
```